# On else its show "Syntax error on token "else", delete this token"

Tags: java

It is source code of my application.I am not getting why this gives error on else keyword.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();// Launches Firefox browser with blank url
    driver.get("http://www.gcrit.com/build3/admin/login.php");
    driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("admin");
    driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("admin@123");
    driver.findElement(By.id("tdb1")).click();

    String url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
    if(url.equals("http://www.gcrit.com/build3/admin/index.php"));
    {
        System.out.println("LOgin Successful--PASS");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Login Unsuccessful--FAIL");
    }
    driver.close();// Closes the browser
}
```

Comment: This question is caused by a typo, and should be closed.

Comment: Delete ; at the end of if clause.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `;` in `if(url.equals("http://www.gcrit.com/build3/admin/index.php"));`. SO your code should be - `if(url.equals("http://www.gcrit.com/build3/admin/index.php"))`

Comment: Ahh ...Sharp eyes :)

Answer (score 0):

You should delete the semicolon at the end of the line that contains your if-statement.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();// Launches Firefox browser with blank url
    driver.get("http://www.gcrit.com/build3/admin/login.php");
    driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("admin");
    driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("admin@123");
    driver.findElement(By.id("tdb1")).click();

    String url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
    if(url.equals("http://www.gcrit.com/build3/admin/index.php"))
    {
        System.out.println("LOgin Successful--PASS");
    }
    else
    {
         System.out.println("Login Unsuccessful--FAIL");
    }
    driver.close();// Closes the browser
 }
```